# Эффект с иконкой при наведении

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, вёрстка

У меня есть вот такой вот макет, где нужно чтобы при наведении появлялась иконка и затемнялся экран. Если с затемнением все понятно, то как добавить иконку при наведении? Желательно на чистом js, но если есть уже готовый вариант на jquery то присылайте.

[image: скрин]

Comment: Можно даже на чистом css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Один из вариантов на чистом CSS:

```css
.blocks{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 280px;
}
.block{
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: #ccc;
  background-position: center;
  transition: .4s;
}

.blocks > .block:nth-child(odd){
  background: #eee;
  background-position: center;
}

.blocks > .block:hover{
  background: url(https://svgsilh.com/svg/1915454-ffffff.svg) no-repeat center #555555;
  background-size: 20px;
  transition: .4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с помощью `JS`, но он избыточен и не нужен, точно такой же эффект получится если заменить на `:hover`

```js
const hovers = document.querySelectorAll('.hover-wrapper');

const enterHandle = function() {
 const target = this.querySelector('.hover-target');
 target.classList.add('active');
}

const leaveHandle = function() {
 const target = this.querySelector('.hover-target');
 target.classList.remove('active');
}

hovers.forEach(hover => {
 hover.addEventListener('mouseenter', enterHandle);
 hover.addEventListener('mouseleave', leaveHandle);
});
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.tiles {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
 grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.tile {
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10%;
 min-height: 33vh;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.tile:nth-child(2n) {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.tile .hover-target {
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 position: absolute;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 opacity: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
 transform: translateY(-100%);
 z-index: 1;
 transition: visibility 0s 0.5s, opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}

.tile .hover-target.active {
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;
 transform: translateY(0);
 transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s, transform 0.5s;
}

.tile img {
 max-width: 25%;
 cursor: help;
}
```

```html
<div class="tiles">
 <div class="tile hover-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci excepturi modi, autem, numquam consequatur accusamus dicta delectus corrupti!</p>
  <div class="hover-target">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2210/2210317.svg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tile hover-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci excepturi modi, autem, numquam consequatur accusamus dicta delectus corrupti!</p>
  <div class="hover-target">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2210/2210317.svg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tile hover-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci excepturi modi, autem, numquam consequatur accusamus dicta delectus corrupti!</p>
  <div class="hover-target">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2210/2210317.svg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tile hover-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci excepturi modi, autem, numquam consequatur accusamus dicta delectus corrupti!</p>
  <div class="hover-target">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2210/2210317.svg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tile hover-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci excepturi modi, autem, numquam consequatur accusamus dicta delectus corrupti!</p>
  <div class="hover-target">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2210/2210317.svg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tile hover-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci excepturi modi, autem, numquam consequatur accusamus dicta delectus corrupti!</p>
  <div class="hover-target">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2210/2210317.svg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tile hover-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci excepturi modi, autem, numquam consequatur accusamus dicta delectus corrupti!</p>
  <div class="hover-target">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2210/2210317.svg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tile hover-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci excepturi modi, autem, numquam consequatur accusamus dicta delectus corrupti!</p>
  <div class="hover-target">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2210/2210317.svg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tile hover-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci excepturi modi, autem, numquam consequatur accusamus dicta delectus corrupti!</p>
  <div class="hover-target">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2210/2210317.svg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

---

Простой вариант с помощью библиотеки `GSAP`

```js
const hovers = document.querySelectorAll('.hover-wrapper');

const enterHandle = function() {
 const target = this.querySelector('.hover-target');

 gsap.to(target, {
  duration: 1,
  yPercent: 0,
  ease: "bounce.out"
 }); 
}

const leaveHandle = function() {
 const target = this.querySelector('.hover-target');

 gsap.to(target, {
  duration: 1,
  yPercent: -100,
  ease: "sine.out",
 });
}

hovers.forEach(hover => {
 const target = hover.querySelector('.hover-target');
 gsap.set(target, { yPercent: -100 });
 
 hover.addEventListener('mouseenter', enterHandle);
 hover.addEventListener('mouseleave', leaveHandle);
});
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
}

.tiles {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
 grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.tile {
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10%;
 min-height: 33vh;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.tile:nth-child(2n) {
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.tile .hover-target {
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 position: absolute;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.tile img {
 max-width: 25%;
 cursor: help;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.2.6/gsap.min.js"></script>
<div class="tiles">
 <div class="tile hover-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci excepturi modi, autem, numquam consequatur accusamus dicta delectus corrupti!</p>
  <div class="hover-target">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2210/2210317.svg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tile hover-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci excepturi modi, autem, numquam consequatur accusamus dicta delectus corrupti!</p>
  <div class="hover-target">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2210/2210317.svg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tile hover-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci excepturi modi, autem, numquam consequatur accusamus dicta delectus corrupti!</p>
  <div class="hover-target">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2210/2210317.svg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tile hover-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci excepturi modi, autem, numquam consequatur accusamus dicta delectus corrupti!</p>
  <div class="hover-target">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2210/2210317.svg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tile hover-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci excepturi modi, autem, numquam consequatur accusamus dicta delectus corrupti!</p>
  <div class="hover-target">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2210/2210317.svg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tile hover-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci excepturi modi, autem, numquam consequatur accusamus dicta delectus corrupti!</p>
  <div class="hover-target">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2210/2210317.svg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tile hover-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci excepturi modi, autem, numquam consequatur accusamus dicta delectus corrupti!</p>
  <div class="hover-target">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2210/2210317.svg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tile hover-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci excepturi modi, autem, numquam consequatur accusamus dicta delectus corrupti!</p>
  <div class="hover-target">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2210/2210317.svg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tile hover-wrapper">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci excepturi modi, autem, numquam consequatur accusamus dicta delectus corrupti!</p>
  <div class="hover-target">
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/2210/2210317.svg" alt="">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```